# p-values from frequency table?

Tags: p-value, frequency

I am doing a data science practice project, seeing if there is any correlation between crime and moon phase.
I have created some frequency tables of crime numbers along with moon phase and it looks like there is no relationship, but how do I show this statistically?

Here is a summary of all the data with moon phase from r:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
    moon    num      freq
  <fctr>  <int>     <dbl>
1    New 463776 0.2512627
2 Waxing 462739 0.2507009
3   Full 459885 0.2491547
4 Waning 459381 0.2488816
```

And an example grouped by crime category:

```
   Category   moon   num     freq
     <fctr> <fctr> <int>    <dbl>
1 Extortion    New   167 0.279732
2 Extortion Waxing   119 0.199330
3 Extortion   Full   143 0.239531
4 Extortion Waning   168 0.281407
```

p-values seem the right way to go with a null hypothesis that there is no difference between moon phases, but what method should I use to get them?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a good case for ANOVA.

Comment: If you just want to do this for one variable at a time then $\chi^2$ goodness of fit would work. Note though that for your first table with such large numbers even a trivial difference will achieve statistical significance.

Comment: Thanks @mdewey the $\chi^2$ goodness of fit was exactly what was looking for.
However now I'm left with, as you said, a statistically significant but trivial difference, which I guess there's nothing I can do except report it as I find it.
If you wanted to write your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.